# I need a simple source code vault for use with vs2010. is there a bare bones version of TFS?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I thought I heard that there was going to be a entry level, low cost version of TFS that is targeted at VSS users who want repository and versioning functionality only. But I can't find the link anymore...does it exist? Or do I need to figure out how to use subversion?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [TFS Basic](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server), an installation option in TFS.
It starts at $500.

Comment: +1. Exactly. 2010 supports basic installation of only source control. Features can be added later as needed (or removed).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend SVN. Go [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/) for TortoiseSVN, an integrated windows shell solution. Alternatively, you could use VisualSVN or any number of other SVN clients, some with VS integration. If you understand the basics of versioning and source control, Tortoise is perfect for you - it's all GUI so you don't need to mess with a CLI unless you want to.